# How to create a diagonal matrix from a sparse Vector

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Suppose `x` is defined as

```
x <- as(c(1,1,0,0,1,0), "sparseVector")
```

I want to create a diagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are given by the entries in `x`.

I tried `Diagonal(x = x)`, but I get the following error.

```
Error in Diagonal(x = x) : 'x' has unsupported class "dsparseVector"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `sparseMatrix`. e.g.:

```
library(Matrix)

x <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0)
x <- sparseMatrix(i = seq(x), j = seq(x), x = x)
x
# 6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                 
# [1,] 1 . . . . .
# [2,] . 1 . . . .
# [3,] . . 0 . . .
# [4,] . . . 0 . .
# [5,] . . . . 1 .
# [6,] . . . . . 0
```

To treat zeros in the original vector as sparse elements:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0)
x <- sparseMatrix(i = which(x!=0), j = which(x!=0), x = x[which(x!=0)], 
  dims = rep(length(x), 2))
x
# 6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                 
# [1,] 1 . . . . .
# [2,] . 1 . . . .
# [3,] . . . . . .
# [4,] . . . . . .
# [5,] . . . . 1 .
# [6,] . . . . . .
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the sparse representation along the diagonal elements as well. That's what I am trying to get (current output shows 0s instead of the dot).

Comment: Updated with an example of treating zeros as sparse elements

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply the `Diagonal` matrix with your sparse vector:

```
Diagonal(length(x)) * x
#6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                
#[1,] 1 . . . . .
#[2,] . 1 . . . .
#[3,] . . . . . .
#[4,] . . . . . .
#[5,] . . . . 1 .
#[6,] . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be constructed from the components of x using sparseMatrix creating an object of dgCMatrix:

```
sparseMatrix(x@i, x@i, x = x@x, dims = c(x@length, x@length))
```

giving:

```
6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                
[1,] 1 . . . . .
[2,] . 1 . . . .
[3,] . . . . . .
[4,] . . . . . .
[5,] . . . . 1 .
[6,] . . . . . .
```

### Note

```
library(Matrix)
x <- as(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), "sparseVector")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `Diagonal(x = as.vector(<sparseVector>))`.  Having said that, it is reasonable to expect `Diagonal(x = <sparseVector>)` to do the same thing. Maybe that is a feature request for Matrix 1.6-1 ...

In any case, the result will be an object inheriting from `diagonalMatrix` and storing zeros on the diagonal explicitly.  Yes, that is "suboptimal", but, in exchange, you benefit from highly optimized methods for `diagonalMatrix`.

If you are only interested in object size, then why not keep the `sparseVector` representation?

```r
library(Matrix)
set.seed(0)
n <- 1e+06L
x0 <- sample(c(0, 1), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1000, 1))
x <- as(x0, "sparseVector")
l <- list(x0 = x0, x = x,
          D = Diagonal(x = as.vector(x)),
          C = sparseMatrix(i = x@i, j = x@i, x = x@x, dims = rep.int(x@length, 2L),
                           triangular = TRUE, repr = "C"),
          R = sparseMatrix(i = x@i, j = x@i, x = x@x, dims = rep.int(x@length, 2L),
                           triangular = TRUE, repr = "R"),
          T = sparseMatrix(i = x@i, j = x@i, x = x@x, dims = rep.int(x@length, 2L), 
                           triangular = TRUE, repr = "T"))
cl <- vapply(l, class, "")
os <- vapply(l, object.size, 0)
data.frame(class = cl, bytes = os, ratio = os/min(os))
```

```
           class   bytes      ratio
x0       numeric 8000048 651.894394
x  dsparseVector   12272   1.000000
D      ddiMatrix 8001240 651.991525
C      dtCMatrix 4013064 327.009778
R      dtRMatrix 4013064 327.009778
T      dtTMatrix   16816   1.370274
```

```r
n. <- as.double(n) # avoid integer overflow in rsparsematrix ... FIXME
M <- rsparsematrix(n., n., 1/n.)
with(l, microbenchmark::microbenchmark(D %*% M, C %*% M, R %*% M, T %*% M))
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
 D %*% M  6.028189  6.502477  6.89017  6.680889  7.13894 10.35902   100
 C %*% M 20.564288 20.793950 21.03865 20.909795 21.07154 24.19648   100
 R %*% M 21.509297 21.793222 22.63789 22.000969 22.49524 63.59588   100
 T %*% M 22.943067 23.205651 24.18345 23.497592 24.09761 64.76713   100
```