# Multiplication of sparse matrices by zero

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Why the following result doesn't store the final answer in sparse format? Is there a way to get this done?

```
library(Matrix)
Diagonal(5) * 0
```

```
5 x 5 diagonal matrix of class "ddiMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    .    .    .    .
[2,]    .    0    .    .    .
[3,]    .    .    0    .    .
[4,]    .    .    .    0    .
[5,]    .    .    .    .    0
```

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/ddiMatrix-class.html

Comment: `Diagonal()` creates a `ddiMatrix` which is just an instance of a sparse matrix under the hood

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want the output to be?  As @Mark points out, this *is* a sparse matrix. (The dots in the output are a giveaway.) Or did you want the result to be *entirely* sparse? i.e. identical to `sparseMatrix(i=integer(0), j = integer(0), x = numeric(0), dims = c(5,5))` ?

Comment: There is  [`drop0`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/drop0.html)  to get of explicit zeros

Comment: @BenBolker I want the matrix to be entirely sparse.

Comment: @user20650, please post `drop0` as an (the) answer ...

Comment: Why do you want to drop zeros from the result?  As I explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76681047/12685768), a `diagonalMatrix` storing diagonal zeros explicitly has advantages over a non-`diagonalMatrix` not storing them (i.e., what `drop0` will give you) ...

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a sparse matrix with package {Matrix}, call `.sparseDiagonal` (or desired variant, see `?Diagonal`).

Example:

```
library(Matrix)

.sparseDiagonal(5) * 0
```

```
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"
              
[1,] 0 . . . .
[2,] . 0 . . .
[3,] . . 0 . .
[4,] . . . 0 .
[5,] . . . . 0
```

compare object sizes in memory:

```
> mat <- diag(1e3) * 0
+ object.size(mat)
> 8000216 bytes

> mat_sparse <- .sparseDiagonal(1e3) * 0
+ object.size(mat_sparse)
> 17792 bytes
```

Comment: the documentation says that .sparseDiagonal creates a `CsparseMatrix`. The documentation for that states `The "CsparseMatrix" class is the virtual class of all sparse matrices coded in sorted compressed column-oriented form. Since it is a virtual class, no objects may be created from it`. I may be misunderstanding this but it seems like this is saying that it's just creating the appearance of something without actually changing anything under the hood

Comment: I added a comparison of the memory taken up by either variant (sparse vs. standard), so there's the expected physical (as far as physical goes in that context) difference, too.

Comment: I get `object.size(Diagonal(1e3) * 0)` as  9240 bytes 

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`drop0`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/drop0.html) so that

> ... "all zero or FALSE entries are dropped from the explicitly indexed matrix entries."

Example

```
> library(Matrix)
> x = Diagonal(5) * 0
> str(x)
Formal class 'ddiMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 4 slots
  ..@ diag    : chr "N"
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 5 5
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0 ### the zeros are indexed
> str(drop0(x))
Formal class 'dtCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 7 slots
  ..@ i       : int(0) 
  ..@ p       : int [1:6] 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 5 5
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num(0)    ### the zeros are no longer indexed
  ..@ uplo    : chr "U"
  ..@ diag    : chr "N"
```